# Como filtrar $_POST['cropData']["width"] com filter_input

Tags: php

Estou tentando filtrar usando esse filtro,

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cropData[width]', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

porem não retorna nada.

Comment: O que esse filtro deveria retornar?

Comment: Valor da largura de uma imagem

Comment: tentou dar um `var_dump()` ai nessa expressão para ver?

Comment: @Gabriel, essa variável é um array ??

Comment: @Oliveira sim ,  e um array

Comment: @Gabriel, coloca o trecho que vc atribui o valor para essa variável!!

Comment: @Oliveira, e por javascript , ele faz _POST com os valores pra dar mudar as dimensões de uma imagem ; exemplo _POST cropData[x]: 0
cropData[y]: 5
cropData[width]: 431
cropData[height]: 324